# Octo print with Pi Cam works fine, added webcam but can't find the Pi cam any more

Tags: webcam, picamera

I've been using my raspberry pi cam module wonderfully for a while and it's attached to the corner of my print bed so I can monitor the first few layers and general build. I want to add a webcam to do better timelapse but still have the raspicam as a stream I can view. When I plug the webcam in, this becomes the primary video stream in the control tab of the octoprint interface. This is not totally unexpected as it explains in the `/boot/octoprint.txt` file it will use the webcam first if detected and the `camera` setting is set to `auto`

I have seen a couple of resources to add multiple webcams by setting an alias based on the camera serial number, then copying the various webcamd scripts but I'm not sure if that's correct here. I was thinking that I can make the /boot/octopi.txt `camera` setting to raspi, then adding another webcam as per those instructions but to use the new alias... Not too sure what to do?

Does anyone else have this setup?

Answer (score 1):

I set the octopi.txt to be the raspi cam so all the defaults would be the bed cam.

I set up the aliases and additional daemons as per this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCxvW1XX44U&index=1&list=LLPMOUAWDulg27cNyuSoEp3g

I then set up octolapse to use the new URLs. Seems to work fine. I have a timelapse from the bed with frames every 10 seconds, and a lovely octolapse from the webcam.